# How to start Racket with xrepl?

Tags: racket

I very often open Racket in bash shell, however in order for it to support xrepl, I need to execute  `(require xrepl)` command first.
Is there any way to start `racket` and execute command above automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Installing XREPL](https://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html#%28part._.Installing_.X.R.E.P.L%29), especially the part I **bolded** below:

> To use XREPL, start racket and enter `(require xrepl)`. You will know that it works when the prompt changes to a `->`, and, if you’re working on a capable terminal, you will now have readline editing. You can also start racket and ask for XREPL to be loaded using command-line arguments:
>
> `racket -il xrepl`
>
> **If you want to enable XREPL automatically, add this expression to your Racket initialization file. An easy way to do the necessary editing is to enter `,install!`**, which will inspect and edit your initialization file (it will describe the change and ask for your permission). Alternatively, you can edit the file directly: on Unix, it is `~/.racketrc`, and for other platforms evaluate `(find-system-path 'init-file)` to see where it is.

Comment: Update: In more-recent versions of Racket, XREPL is enabled by default in the Racket REPL when the `xrepl-lib` package is installed.